# Why does my pong code have a ParseError and how do I fix it?

Tags: python-3.x, parse-error

This is a pong game I made a long time ago, but it gave me an error when I revisited it, it says: ParseError: Bad input on line 158, How can I fix this? Will there be more errors? Can I Improve the code?
Here is my code(I hope it's not because I'm using a different version)(Also The code is to long so here is the part that doesn't work):

```
if P1.ycor() - 100 < ball_hitbox.ycor() < P1.ycor() + 100 and abs(P1.xcor() - ball_hitbox.xcor()) < 20:
    if 0 <= ball_hitbox.heading() < 180:
      ball_hitbox.setheading(180 - ball_hitbox.heading())
    elif 180 <= ball_hitbox.heading() < 360:
      ball_hitbox.setheading(540 - ball_hitbox.heading())
    touchey = 'P1 Touchey, bad P1'
  #P2 bounce
  elif P2.ycor() - 100 < ball_hitbox.ycor() < P2.ycor() + 100 and abs(P2.xcor() - ball_hitbox.xcor()) < 20:
    if 0 <= ball_hitbox.heading() < 180:
      ball_hitbox.setheading(180 - ball_hitbox.heading())
    elif 180 <= ball_hitbox.heading() < 360:
      ball_hitbox.setheading(540 - ball_hitbox.heading())
    touchey = 'P2 Touchey, bad P2'
  #P3 bounce
  elif P3.xcor() - 100 < ball_hitbox.xcor() < P3.xcor() + 100 and abs(P3.ycor() - ball_hitbox.ycor()) < 20:
    ball_hitbox.setheading(360 - ball_hitbox.heading())
    touchey = 'P3 Touchey, bad P3'
  #P4 bounce
  elif P4.xcor() - 100 < ball_hitbox.xcor() < P4.xcor() + 100 and abs(P4.ycor() - ball_hitbox.ycor()) < 20:
    ball_hitbox.setheading(360 - ball_hitbox.heading())
    touchey = 'P4 Touchey, bad P4'
    print(P1_Score + P2_Score + P3_Score + P4_Score)
  if ball_hitbox.xcor() >= 597:
    if touchey == 'P1 Touchey, bad P1':
      P1_Score += 1
    elif touchey == 'P3 Touchey, bad P3':
      P3_Score += 1
    elif touchey == 'P4 Touchey, bad P4':
      P4_Score += 1
    ball_hitbox.goto(0,0)
    ball_hitbox.setheading(rnd.randint(0,359))

    ball_hitbox.goto(0,0)
  if ball_hitbox.xcor() <= -597:
    if touchey == 'P2 Touchey, bad P2':
      P2_Score += 1
    elif touchey == 'P3 Touchey, bad P3':
      P3_Score += 1
    elif touchey == 'P4 Touchey, bad P4':
      P4_Score += 1
    ball_hitbox.goto(0,0)
    ball_hitbox.setheading(rnd.randint(0,359)

  if ball_hitbox.ycor() >= 288: # This line has the error
    if touchey == 'P1 Touchey, bad P1':
      P1_Score += 1
    elif touchey == 'P2 Touchey, bad P2':
      P2_Score += 1
    elif touchey == 'P4 Touchey, bad P4':
      P4_Score += 1
    ball_hitbox.goto(0,0)
    ball_hitbox.setheading(rnd.randint(0,359))
```

Comment: Please add you code here, do not post it in external links. Also, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a post of how to make a question on SO.

Comment: The line before it is missing a closing bracket `)`.

Comment: Thank you kaya13! :)